# Linearly scale axes from kilometers to meters for all plots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am working with data in meters and want to plot positions. Having the ticks in meters is obscuring the readability of the plots, so I want to plot the data in kilometers. I know that it is possible to scale all data `d/1000.`, however, this makes the code less readable in my eyes, especially if you're plotting many different lines, where you have to do this transformation every time.

I am looking for a general way to achieve this type of transformation, I could imagine there is a beautiful way to achieve this in matplotlib.

Some sample code for you:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(7500, 30000, 300)
y_ref = np.linspace(5000, 15000, 300)
y_noised = y_ref + np.random.normal(0, 250, size=y_ref.size)

fig = plt.Figure(figsize=(6,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

ax.plot(x, y_ref, c='r')
ax.scatter(x, y_noised, alpha=0.2)
fig
```

[image: Output figure]

I would like to have the following figure, **without** needing to scale `x`, `y_ref` and `y_noised` individually by `1000`.

[image: Desired output]

Is there a way to perform this transformation in matplotlib, such that you only need to do it for each figure **once**, no matter how many lines you plot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a custom tick formatter like that (passing a function into [`set_major_formatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_major_formatter.html#matplotlib-axis-axis-set-major-formatter) creates a `FuncFormatter`):

```
m2km = lambda x, _: f'{x/1000:g}'
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(m2km)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(m2km)
```

[image]

Comment: Great! That's what I've been looking for. Just for future reference: This formatter does not work with the "offset notation" in plots with large values. In case someone encounters this problem in the future, it will probably not be too hard to write an own Formatter, that sets the offset for large values explicitly. But for me it works as is!